# Is there a way to order a list by two substrings in python?

Tags: python

Hi I need to retrieve a list of files within a folder ordering by two substrings.

The file names are like this:

```
503-03-Mar-2022..csv
604-07-Apr-2022..csv
503-17-Mar-2022..csv
604-16-Mar-2022..csv
```

I need to retrieve the latest file for each of the first three numbers.

So I'd have something like:

```
503 - 17-Mar-2022
604 - 16-Mar-2022
```

I'm retrieving the information as such:

```
import os, pandas as pd, myLibrary    
csvPath = r"C:\csvs"    
l = os.listdir(csvPath)
str = l[0]
count = 0
for path in os.listdir(csvPath):
    if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(csvPath, path)):
        count += 1
courseList = [i.split('-', 1)[0] for i in l]
tempList = [i.split('-', 1)[1] for i in l]
dateList = [i.split('..', 1)[0] for i in tempList]
sizeCourseList = len(courseList)
bit503 = courseList.count("503")
bit604 = courseList.count("604")
bit606 = courseList.count("606")
bit607 = courseList.count("607")
df = pd.read_csv(csvPath+"\\"+l[0])
print(l)
```

If you could point me in the right direction I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Do you know how to order things *at all* in Python? For example, have you seen the built-in standard library `sorted` function, or the `sort` method of lists?

Comment: As a side note, `07-Apr-2022` is a _terrible_ filename if you need to sort by date.  `2022-04-07` is _much_ better.

Comment: @rod the question isn't formulated appropriately for StackOverflow here we usually expect questions to be https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example which includes the output you expect and what the current output (usually not what you expect)  looks like.

Comment: Hi Lucas, I put the whole code I'm using so it should be reproducible.

Comment: Hi John, I don't have control on how the files are named.

Comment: Hi Karl, Yes I checked but was wondering if it was possible to sort by two elements in this case two substrings...

Comment: Can you just use the sort function in python? You're able to make a custom comparator function, such as `mylist.sort(key = lambda a: int(a[:3]))`

Comment: `I need to retrieve the latest file for each of the first three numbers.` What do you mean by "latest file"? The latest date? Because in the example you posted, `604-07-Apr-2022..csv` as a latest date than `604 - 16-Mar-2022`. Could you explain it better?

Answer (score 0):

```
from datetime import datetime
from itertools import groupby

files = [
  '503-03-Mar-2022..csv',
  '604-07-Apr-2022..csv',
  '503-17-Mar-2022..csv',
  '604-16-Mar-2022..csv'
]

def f(s):
  k1 = s[:3]
  k2 = datetime.strptime(s[4:15], '%d-%b-%Y')
  return (k1, k2.day, k2.month)

files.sort(key=f)
print(files) # ['503-03-Mar-2022..csv', '503-17-Mar-2022..csv', '604-07-Apr-2022..csv', '604-16-Mar-2022..csv']
result = [list(g)[-1] for _, g in groupby(files, lambda s: s[:3])]
print(result) # ['503-17-Mar-2022..csv', '604-16-Mar-2022..csv']
```

1. We take the first three fields, and convert those to a tuple of 3 integers, which is used to sort the list.
2. We group by the first element of the tuple, and take the last element from the list that has the latest date.